# SQL Results Missing When Adding Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct

Trying to figure out an issue that is causing my SQL Server query to return no results.  I have a query which calls out where there is more than one unique 'requested delivery date' at a size level on a single PO.  I do this using `COUNT`and `DISTINCT`.  It works perfect until I add the fields 'PO_ITEM_NUMBER' and 'REQ_DELIV_DATE'- this was requested by the business.  I am not sure why that would cause an issue - for reference our tier for PO tables is Header,Item,Size - size being the most granular and it is SAP based.

Query:

```
SELECT E.TEAM_MEMBER_NAME [EMPLOYEE],
       H.PO_TYPE,
       H.PO_ISSUE_DATE,
       S.PO_NUMBER,
       S.MATERIAL,
       M.DESCRIPTION,
       H.PO_ORDERED_QUANTITY [PO_QUANTITY], -- if you sue SUM(S.PO_ORDERED_QUANTITY - you get more results but wrong totals
       K.BUSINESS_SEGMENT_DESC,
       S.PO_REQ_DELIV_DATE,
       S.PO_ITEM_NUMBER


FROM   PDX_SAP_USER..VW_PO_SIZE S --- you can use .. insetead of .dbo.
JOIN   ADI_USER_MAINTAINED..SCM_PO_Employee_Name E --- join the po to employee assigment table
ON     S.PO_NUMBER = E.PO_NUMBER
JOIN   PDX_SAP_USER..VW_PO_HEADER H 
ON     E.PO_NUMBER = H.PO_NUMBER 
JOIN   PDX_SAP_USER..VW_PO_ITEM I 
ON     E.PO_NUMBER = I.PO_NUMBER 
JOIN   PDX_SAP_USER..VW_MM_MATERIAL M 
ON     E.MATERIAL = M.MATERIAL 
JOIN   PDX_SAP_USER..vw_kd_BUSINESS_SEGMENT K 
ON     M.BUSINESS_SEGMENT_CODE = K.BUSINESS_SEGMENT_CODE

WHERE  I.PO_BALANCE_QUANTITY > 0 ---exclude any fully received PO's
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM VW_PO_ITEM I1 WHERE DEL_INDICATOR = 'L' AND I.PO_NUMBER = I1.PO_NUMBER)

GROUP BY S.PO_NUMBER, 
         E.TEAM_MEMBER_NAME, 
         H.PO_TYPE, 
         H.PO_ISSUE_DATE, 
         S.MATERIAL, 
         M.DESCRIPTION,
         K.BUSINESS_SEGMENT_DESC,
         H.PO_ORDERED_QUANTITY,
         S.PO_REQ_DELIV_DATE,
         S.PO_ITEM_NUMBER

HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT S.PO_REQ_DELIV_DATE) > 1

ORDER BY S.PO_NUMBER
```

Adding query that works along with the results:

```
SELECT E.TEAM_MEMBER_NAME [EMPLOYEE],
       H.PO_TYPE,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),H.PO_ISSUE_DATE,101) [PO_ISSUE_DATE],
       S.PO_NUMBER,
       S.MATERIAL,
       M.DESCRIPTION,
       H.PO_ORDERED_QUANTITY [PO_QUANTITY], --- if you use SUM(S.PO_ORDERED_QUANTITY) - you get more results but wrong totals
       K.BUSINESS_SEGMENT_DESC


FROM   PDX_SAP_USER..VW_PO_SIZE S --- you can use .. insetead of .dbo.
JOIN   ADI_USER_MAINTAINED..SCM_PO_Employee_Name E --- join the po to employee assigment table
ON     S.PO_NUMBER = E.PO_NUMBER
JOIN   PDX_SAP_USER..VW_PO_HEADER H 
ON     E.PO_NUMBER = H.PO_NUMBER 
JOIN   PDX_SAP_USER..VW_PO_ITEM I 
ON     E.PO_NUMBER = I.PO_NUMBER 
JOIN   PDX_SAP_USER..VW_MM_MATERIAL M 
ON     E.MATERIAL = M.MATERIAL 
JOIN   PDX_SAP_USER..vw_kd_BUSINESS_SEGMENT K 
ON     M.BUSINESS_SEGMENT_CODE = K.BUSINESS_SEGMENT_CODE

WHERE  I.PO_BALANCE_QUANTITY > 0 ---exclude any fully received PO's
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM VW_PO_ITEM I1 WHERE DEL_INDICATOR = 'L' AND I.PO_NUMBER = I1.PO_NUMBER)

GROUP BY S.PO_NUMBER, 
         E.TEAM_MEMBER_NAME, 
         H.PO_TYPE, 
         H.PO_ISSUE_DATE, 
         S.MATERIAL, 
         M.DESCRIPTION,
         K.BUSINESS_SEGMENT_DESC,
         H.PO_ORDERED_QUANTITY

HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT S.PO_REQ_DELIV_DATE) > 1

ORDER BY S.PO_NUMBER
```

Results:

```
EMPLOYEE                       PO_TYPE PO_ISSUE_DATE PO_NUMBER  MATERIAL           DESCRIPTION                              PO_QUANTITY                             BUSINESS_SEGMENT_DESC
------------------------------ ------- ------------- ---------- ------------------ ---------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Christopher Olson              NB      01/19/2017    0282238419 CD7078             ESS 3S PANT WVN                          2054                                    CORE APP MEN SPORT ADIDAS
Juan Gomez                     NB      02/23/2017    0282524995 S98775             ESS LIN P/O FT                           103                                     CORE APP MEN SPORT ADIDAS
Christopher Olson              NB      03/09/2017    0282598957 BK7410             ESS LGO T P SJ                           619                                     ATHLETICS APP MEN ADIDAS
Juan Gomez                     NB      03/28/2017    0282706115 S97155             ESS LIN TIGHT                            961                                     CORE APP WOMEN SPORT ADIDAS
Juan Gomez                     NB      09/21/2017    0283752965 CF8152             BOS LABEL                                7900                                    ATHLETICS APP MEN ADIDAS
Julie Lange-May                12      10/02/2017    0283796594 DQ1421             WOVEN JACKET W                           1020                                    ATHLETICS APP WOMEN ADIDAS
Kekai Ariola                   NB      10/10/2017    0283837426 AC7366             PW HU HOLI Tennis Hu MC                  5655                                    STATEMENT FTW ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      11/10/2017    0283944933 DB2061             PREDATOR TANGO 18.1 TR                   1756                                    FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Andrew Zapata                  05      11/13/2017    0283961402 CG6440             NEMEZIZ 18.1 FG W                        543                                     FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Christopher Olson              NB      11/20/2017    0283981666 CV7748             ASSITA 17 GK Y                           1648                                    FOOTBALL APP GENERIC ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      11/21/2017    0283984539 DB2165             COPA 18.1 FG                             501                                     FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Julie Lange-May                NB      11/26/2017    0284043157 CE4368             I GRPHC STSET                            1333                                    ORIGINALS APP KIDS ADIDAS
Trey Pflug                     NB      11/27/2017    0284048754 CQ3168             SOLAR BOOST M                            3500                                    RUNNING FTW MEN ADIDAS
Dave Laws                      NB      11/28/2017    0284059045 DB2966             YEEZY 500                                15334                                   YEEZY FTW ADIDAS
Dave Laws                      NB      11/28/2017    0284059047 DB2966             YEEZY 500                                12584                                   YEEZY FTW ADIDAS
Christopher Olson              NB      12/06/2017    0284094060 BJ9165             TASTIGO17 SHO W                          7522                                    FOOTBALL APP GENERIC ADIDAS
Christopher Olson              NB      12/06/2017    0284094212 BK0350             TIRO17 TRG PNTW                          7091                                    FOOTBALL APP GENERIC ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      12/08/2017    0284107301 DB2062             PREDATOR TANGO 18.1 TR                   2110                                    FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Trey Pflug                     NB      12/11/2017    0284115640 BC0674             SOLAR BOOST W                            1752                                    RUNNING FTW WOMEN ADIDAS
Kim Moreland                   NB      12/12/2017    0284137355 DJ3033             D2M K SHT                                1730                                    CORE APP WOMEN SPORT ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      12/12/2017    0284141196 DB2126             PREDATOR TANGO 18.3 IN                   1988                                    FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      12/12/2017    0284141253 AQ0612             NEMEZIZ MESSI TANGO 18.3 TF              526                                     FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Dave Laws                      NB      12/15/2017    0284170426 DB2966             YEEZY 500                                2918                                    YEEZY FTW ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      12/16/2017    0284174671 DB2248             X 18.1 FG                                668                                     FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      12/16/2017    0284174673 DB2039             PREDATOR 18.1 FG                         489                                     FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Christopher Olson              ER      12/20/2017    0284207872 BS4250             TASTIGO17 SHO                            404                                     FOOTBALL APP GENERIC ADIDAS
Ben Paul                       NB      12/19/2017    0284208137 CG0584             REAL A JSY                               811                                     FOOTBALL APP LICENSED ADIDAS
Julie Lange-May                NB      01/07/2018    0284316616 DN4273             UAS BEANIE                               120                                     ORIGINALS APP MEN ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      01/08/2018    0284319552 DB2063             PREDATOR TANGO 18.1 TR                   2001                                    FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      01/19/2018    0284464341 DB2214             X 18+ FG                                 582                                     FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      01/19/2018    0284464343 DB2013             PREDATOR 18+ FG                          2201                                    FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      01/19/2018    0284464344 DB2072             NEMEZIZ 18+ FG                           1467                                    FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      01/19/2018    0284464346 DB2251             X 18.1 FG                                620                                     FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      01/19/2018    0284464348 DB2167             COPA 18.1 FG                             1714                                    FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      01/19/2018    0284464349 DB2089             NEMEZIZ MESSI 18.1 FG                    988                                     FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      01/19/2018    0284464350 DB2040             PREDATOR 18.1 FG                         2061                                    FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      01/19/2018    0284465944 DB2001             PREDATOR 18.3 FG                         7008                                    FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      01/23/2018    0284489924 772109             SAMBA CLASSIC                            419                                     FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Andrew Zapata                  05      02/02/2018    0284539184 DH3869             CLIMA 3.0 TEE                            1853                                    ACTION SPORTS APP ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      02/06/2018    0284550445 BB0571             Goletto VI FG J                          5562                                    FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      02/24/2018    0284666220 DM2092             MLS ASG OMB                              424                                     FOOTBALL ACC HW ADIDAS
Christopher Olson              NB      01/19/2018    0284666914 BP9111             D2M 3S SHORT                             11811                                   CORE APP MEN SPORT ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      02/27/2018    0284684097 019228             MUNDIAL TEAM                             657                                     FOOTBALL FTW ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      03/06/2018    0284704098 CD4683             GENERICWCBOX                             80000                                   FOOTBALL ACC HW ADIDAS
Kekai Ariola                   NB      03/08/2018    0284728508 BB7619             Sobakov                                  1775                                    ORIGINALS FTW MEN ADIDAS
Kim Moreland                   NB      03/08/2018    0284730274 BP9733             ULT SS T                                 2557                                    TRAINING APP MEN ADIDAS
Kekai Ariola                   05      03/27/2018    0284865999 B37532             EQT SUPPORT SK PK W                      347                                     ORIGINALS FTW WOMEN ADIDAS
Kekai Ariola                   05      03/27/2018    0284866000 B37545             EQT SUPPORT SK PK W                      357                                     ORIGINALS FTW WOMEN ADIDAS
Kim Moreland                   NB      04/06/2018    0284914322 DH3591             Tech Tee                                 10042                                   TRAINING APP WOMEN ADIDAS
Cody Lofquist                  NB      04/10/2018    0284930265 CW5627             Pred FS JR MN                            1651                                    FOOTBALL ACC HW ADIDAS
Kekai Ariola                   NB      04/10/2018    0284930449 B41794             PW TENNIS HU                             315                                     ORIGINALS FTW MEN ADIDAS

(51 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? And how did the query look before the changes?

Comment: You added them to `group by` which obviously is going to change the behavior.

Comment: I add them to group by because I am using the having clause - I was under the impression it was mandatory.

Comment: You make the groups smaller by splitting them up and so fewer of them matched.

Comment: And beyond that, you can't have a group with more than one distinct value in a column when you're grouping on it too. That's the definition of a group.

Comment: I think you are referring to the req_deliv_date?  if I get rid of that in the select and group by i get results - just not as many  - apologies I am working through this as I go.  Thanks.

Comment: the idea is I want to see cases where a PO has more than one unique req_deliv_date and I also want to see the lines showing the different dates - I assumed that COUNT DISTINCT was the best option - any ideas of a better one? thanks again for the input

Comment: Been fiddling with my answer. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: What do you expect? When `S.PO_REQ_DELIV_DATE` is part of the `GROUP BY` your `COUNT(DISTINCT S.PO_REQ_DELIV_DATE)` will always return 1.

Comment: @dnoeth - I appreciate the response, I cannot leave it out of the GROUP BY if I am understanding correctly?  That is my issue - apologies for any confusion

Answer (score 0):

```
If you added HAVING clause recently then comment and check.  
If not then change the INNER JOIN TO LEFT join from bottom to top one at a time and execute the query and check.
This way you can troubleshoot the issue easily.
Unless we have the sample data for all the tables you are used the query it will be difficult to answer.
```

Comment: no luck with changing the joins I can provide the sample query when it worked along with the data.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH POsToReturn AS (
SELECT S.PO_NUMBER   
FROM   PDX_SAP_USER..VW_PO_SIZE S 
JOIN   PDX_SAP_USER..VW_PO_ITEM I 
ON     I.PO_NUMBER = S.PO_NUMBER 
WHERE  I.PO_BALANCE_QUANTITY > 0
GROUP BY S.PO_NUMBER
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT S.PO_REQ_DELIV_DATE) > 1
AND COUNT(CASE WHEN I.DEL_INDICATOR = 'L' THEN 1 END) = 0
)
SELECT <your columns>
FROM   POsToReturn P
JOIN   PDX_SAP_USER..VW_PO_SIZE S
ON     S.PO_NUMBER = P.PO_NUMBER
...    <join the rest of the tables for the detail columns>
--     leave out the entire group by!
```

Or you could go with an approach like this:

```
with data as (
    select
        count(distinct S.PO_REQ_DELIV_DATE)
            over (partition by S.PO_NUMBER) as rdd_count
        <insert rest of main query>
)
select ... from data
where rdd_count > 1
order by S.PO_NUMBER;
```

As for understanding why, I think you've seen other queries where people added columns to a `group by` clause so they could get around a mysterious error message about non-aggregates. If not that then you've seen those systems that confusingly permit a non-standard behavior that gives results without erroring at all.

Usually what people want to accomplish is something like this: I'm grouping on Customer ID already but I want Customer Name in the results too. So they add that extra column to the 'group by' list and everything works fine. But if you think about it the reason is that the new column didn't change the groups at all since each Customer ID always has the same Customer Name anyway and it's ultimately just an easy way to get rid of the error. In your query that's not true though: you do have more than one date in *all* the groups you care about.

In my opinion it's better to use dummy aggregates like `min(Customer Name) as CustomerName`. Remember an aggregate function's purpose is collapsing multiple values into a single value. When necessary some systems will just pick a value at random, without warning you it did that. Many MySQL and Sybase developers got burned by this when they relied on this quirky behavior and/or never really learned how it's supposed to work.

Also remember that in general a group is a set of multiple rows collapsed into just one row. For `count(distinct)` to work it needed to see multiple dates *across a single group*. But that conflicts with your need to keep the output as separate rows.

Essentially the row by itself doesn't give you enough information to decide whether to keep it. I solved that by using a second query to figure a list of `PO_Number`s meeting the criteria and then using that as a filter (via inner join.)

In the second example I used a window function instead, which lets you look outside each row without the row-collapsing behavior of `group by`. Both of the basically let you do what the `having` was intended to accomplish.

Comment: both answers are great - I am curious if you may know why it wouldn't work - that is one of my main questions.  Appreciate the help and i need to start using CTE more!

Comment: @user3496218 Explanation added